# Draggable div not being dragged using Hammerjs and Angular

Tags: angular, hammer

In my angular app I have cards and spaces, me cards(divs) can dragged and relocated fine on desktop, and I'm trying to use hammerjs to get it to work on mobile.

[image]

So I have added a `(pan)` event handler, which is being fired fine.

```html
<div class="cardSpace" [ngClass]="debugStyle ? 'redBorder':''" [attr.id]="cardSpace.id" (click)="toggleCard()"
    [draggable]="!cardSpace.isEmpty" (dragstart)="drag($event)" (dragover)="allowDrop($event)" (drop)="drop($event)"
    (pan)="onPan($event)" [style.left.px]="left" [style.top.px]="top">
    <ng-container *ngIf="!cardSpace.isEmpty;">
        <img class="cardSize" [src]="getImagePath()">
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

here is the logic for the event handler

```js
//mobile drag
onPan(event: any) {
    const elem = event.target;
    const el = new ElementRef(document.getElementById(this.cardSpace.id));

    if (!this.isDragging) {
      this.isDragging = true;

      this.lastPosX = 40;
      this.lastPosY = 80;
      /* did not work either
      if (el.nativeElement) {
        this.lastPosX = el.nativeElement.style.left;
        this.lastPosX = el.nativeElement.style.top;
      }
      */
      /* did not work 
      this.lastPosX = elem.offsetLeft;
      this.lastPosY = elem.offsetTop;
      */
    }

    // move our element to that position
    this.left = event.deltaX + this.lastPosX;
    this.top = event.deltaY + this.lastPosY;

    if (event.isFinal) {
      this.isDragging = false;
    }

    this.debugStyle = this.isDragging;
}
```

When I test the drag on mobile the card border is turning red when the drag starts (as expected) but the card(div) is not being moved even though I'm updating the left/top values used to locate the element.

The cards are layout initially in a row (flex container) - https://gallant-agnesi-5c5b96.netlify.app/ or a Matrix (one row above the other)

```html
<div class="cardRow">

    <div *ngFor="let cs of cardSpaces; let i = index">
        <ng-container *ngIf="hasHeaders">
            <div class="header">
                {{ headers[i] }}
            </div>
        </ng-container>
        <app-card-space-component [cardSpace]="cs" (dragStarted)="dragStarted($event)"
            (dragFinished)="dragFinished($event)"></app-card-space-component>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do I need to "float" my div so that is not constrained by the cardRow ? what I'm doing wrong here ?

References:

- https://codepen.io/bladnman/pen/LEWYYN
- https://embed.plnkr.co/vcD5EX/

Also I'm looking for a way to debug in mobile, since console.log errors are not very useful there.

Comment: Did you already consider using [@angular/cdk/drag-drop](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#cdk-drag-drop-overview)? (No it has **nothing** to do with angular/material)

Comment: I started with CDKdroplist for each row but I don't need my list to grow when a new item is drag into it, and could not find an example for that, so I moved to custom drag and drop

Answer (score 0):

The reason the `div` was not being dragged is because the `display` was not set to `absolute`, to allow to be moved outside of its container.

So adding this style to the div, made it float

```css
.redBorder {
    border: 1px red solid; //only for debug purposes
    position: absolute; //<---- this was the solution
}
```

When the drag starts I set the flag to make it draggable (position: absolute)
and when the drag ends I remove that style

```js
onPan(event: any) {
    const elem = event.target;

    if (!this.isDragging) {
      this.isDragging = true;

      this.lastPosX = elem.offsetLeft;
      this.lastPosY = elem.offsetTop;
    }

    // move our element to that position
    this.left = event.deltaX + this.lastPosX;
    this.top = event.deltaY + this.lastPosY;

    if (event.isFinal) {
      this.isDragging = false;
    }

    this.debugStyle = this.isDragging;
}
```